# Pasar objetos java a stored procedure en oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Estoy teniendo un problema al tratar de pasar un objeto o arreglo desde java a un store en mi base de datos. Lo que pasa es que cuando trato de pasa una atributo que es string, este se está asignando vacío  en el objeto STRUCT
el código es el siguiente

```
StructDescriptor itemDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("USUARIO.TY_REG_CORRESP",oracleConn);

         STRUCT[] idsArray = new STRUCT[registros.size()];
         int index=0;
         Map< String, Object> map = null;
        for (DatosArchivoTO registro:registros){
            map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("VALOR", registro.getLinea());
            map.put("NUMERO_LINEA", registro.getNumLinea());
            /*Object[] itemAtributes = new Object[2];
            itemAtributes[0]=new String(registro.getLinea());
            itemAtributes[1]=registro.getNumLinea();*/

            STRUCT itemObject = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor,oracleConn,map);
            idsArray[index]=itemObject;
            index++;
        }

        ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("USUARIO.TY_LISTA_REG_CORRESP",oracleConn);
        ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc,oracleConn ,idsArray);
```

Al hacer el debug me encuentro que no se está asignando bien el primer valor en el objeto itemObject

```
datumArray [???, oracle.sql.NUMBER@4ff353fd]
```

Los objetos en la base de datos son los siguientes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TY_REG_CORRESP AS OBJECT (VALOR VARCHAR2(200),
                                         NUMERO_LINEA NUMBER(9))
```

y

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TY_LISTA_REG_CORRESP AS TABLE OF USUARIO.TY_REG_CORRESP
```

Como ultimo tengo un stored procedure que recibe el arreglo de objetos y al tratar de insertar los datos en la tabla solo insert el valor entero y el valor string como nulo.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Pues después de casi un día entero encontré la solución al problema y es la siguiente:

Al parecer se trata de un problema de encoding entre la base de datos y el cliente para lo cual la solución que encontré es que se tiene que agregar la lib orai18n.jar al proyecto esto resuelve el problema.